# How to remove Offcanvas animation?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

A bootstrap's Modal has the `fade` class that animates it when it is shown. `OffCanvas` has such an animation too but there is no corresponding `fade` class.

Is there a workaround to remove the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inspection of the structure in the [demo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/offcanvas/#live-demo) shows a transition property on the .offcanvas class. So just remove that.

```
.offcanvas {
  transition: none;
}
```